# django-reversion conflict with models clean method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-reversion

i use django-reversion to controll changes of my models but i have a problem with the models clean method.

For example my model looks like this:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    template = models.ForeignKey(Template, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def clean(self):
        if self.template.only_one and (Document.objects.filter(client=self.client, template=self.template).count() > 0):
            raise ValidationError('Test')
```

I register this model in the admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Document)
class DocumentReversion(VersionAdmin):
    pass
```

Now i create a record for Document in the admin section referencing to a template where the field `only_one` is `True`.
If i delete this record and retrieve it, a ValidationError fires.
Why? Because i have deleted the only available record. Very curious...

Comment: Because `clean()` is called on the existing document, hence `self.template.only_one` and `Document.objects.filter(...).count()` is true as well, and therefore it raises an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clean is performed on any update. If you thus *edit* your `Document`, then it will check the given condition as well. Since that condition holds: the template has `only_one=True`, and there is such document (your document), it will thus raise a `ValidationError`.

You thus need to exclude the current item from the queryset:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    template = models.ForeignKey(Template, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def clean(self):
        qs = Document.objects.filter(client_id=self.client_id, template_id=self.template_id)
        if self.pk is not None:
            qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.pk)
        if self.template.only_one and qs.exists():
            raise ValidationError('A document with this template already exists')
        return super().clean()
```

If the primary key is thus set, we can exclude that primary key from the queryset. In fact we do not need the if condition here, since `.exclude(pk=None)` will always succeed anyway.